# a simple client/server chat program

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm trying to create a simple chat program using java, which contains to forms, a client form and a server form, the client form contains a TextField and a Button (send button), and the server form contains a TextArea.

When I click on the send button it should send the wrote text in the TextField to the TextArea in the server form.

for the first time it works but when I click on the button in the second time it won't work.

this is the code I used in the Server Form :

```
public class Server extends javax.swing.JFrame implements Runnable {

    private Thread th;

    public Server() {
        initComponents();
        th = new Thread(this);
        th.start();
    }

    // The main method was here

    @Override
    public void run() {

        // Etablir la connexion
        try {
            ServerSocket ecoute;
            ecoute = new ServerSocket(1111);
            Socket service = null;
            System.out.println("Serveur en attente d'un client !");
            while (true) {

                service = ecoute.accept();
                System.out.println("Client connécté !");
                DataInputStream is = new DataInputStream(service.getInputStream());
                jTextArea1.setText("Client dit : "+ is.readUTF().toUpperCase());
                service.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
}
```

and this is the code of the client form:

```
    public class Client extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    DataOutputStream os;

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        try {
            os.writeUTF(jTextField1.getText());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,null, ex);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                Client c = new Client();
                c.setVisible(true);

                try {
                    Socket s = new Socket("localhost", 1111);
                    c.os = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: "*for the first time it works but when I click on the button in the second time it won't work.*". So what happens then? Be specific.

Comment: @Lion nothing happens, It does anything, it seems like the Action event works only once

Comment: No exception gets logged? That seems strange..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in the server's code:
to receive various messages from various clients at the server's side,
for each accept, i.e. each client, you have to create one thread to process its requests, because you are using TCP connections. (- you were only processing one request per accept, and then closing the connection).

I cleaned the parts unrelated to sockets of your code, (i.e. some incomplete parts related to the GUI in the client), so I present a different version that works well for many simultaneous clients' connections, and you can see all the messages arriving to the server, and not only the 1st message.

**servers' code:**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;


public class Server {

    public static void run() {
        try
        {
            ServerSocket ecoute;
            ecoute = new ServerSocket(1111);
            Socket service = null;
            System.out.println("serveur en attente d'un client!");
            while(true)
            {
                service = ecoute.accept();
                System.out.println("client connécté!");
//              ##call a new thread
                WorkerThread wt = new WorkerThread(service);
                wt.start();
            }
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        run();
    }
}


class WorkerThread extends Thread {
    Socket service;
    WorkerThread(Socket service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    public void run() {
    boolean flag=true;    //you can change this flag's condition, to test if the client disconects
    try
    {
        while (flag){
            DataInputStream is = new DataInputStream(service.getInputStream());
            System.out.println("client dit: " + is.readUTF().toUpperCase());
        }
        service.close();
    }
    catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**clients' code:**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.logging.*;


public class Client {

DataOutputStream os;

public static void main(String args[]) {
java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
               Client c = new Client();
        try {
            Socket s = new Socket("localhost", 1111);
            c.os = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
            while (true){
                String str = Input.read_string();
                c.os.writeUTF(str);
            }
        } catch ( IOException e) {
            // TODO auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
            }
        });
    }
}

public class Input{
    public static String read_string(){
        String read="";
        try{
            read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in), 1).readLine();
        }catch (IOException ex){
            System.out.println("error reading from the input stream!");
        }
        return read;
    }
}
```

After that, you need, as you probably know, to send all those messages that arrive to the server to all the clients in the chat room.

Answer (score 1):

In your `while(true)` section of the `Server` code - you are closing the socket after you read it once, while at the client you do not reopen a `Socket` (and a new `InputStream`). What I suggest is that you have another loop in your `while(true)` section that will keep on reading and display new data until the EOF is reached.

Comment: I dont know where I have to use the other while(true) loop

Comment: He doesn't need to reopen a socket at the client's side, as he is using TCP. He needs to continue the processing of the messages at the server's side, and a simple while(true) loop at the servers' side would not be enough because it would support only one client...